Modules not found when installing Tailwind or any framework
I succesfully installed Node.js on my PC and I'm trying to install TailwindCSS using TailwindCLI, via npm. I had run the command in the VSCode terminal, and the error shown below occured.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.13.0

I tried to reinstall Node.js but it didn't solve my problem. This problem occurs specifically in VSCode, as I tried to install Tailwind in the Command Prompt and it worked, but I need it in VSCode in order for it to create automatically the files requiered. A solution for me is a method to create manually those files (package.json, package-lock.json)
